# ambiguous call to overloaded function with "bind" when i add header file"boost/function"

Tags: visual-studio-2012, c++11, boost, bind

I write a test of boost::function.
These codes are working.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
//#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/ref.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace boost;
template<typename FUN,typename T>
T fun( FUN function, T lhs, T rhs ){
    cout << typeid(function).name() << endl;
    return function(lhs,rhs);
}
int add4(int a, int b, int c){
    return a + b + c;
}
int main(){
    cout << fun(bind(add4,2,_1,_2),1,4) << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

But when i add header file "boost/funcation"
VS2012 prompts me it.

`error C2668: 'std::bind' : ambiguous call to overloaded function.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't import both `std` and `boost` namespaces into the global namespace, to avoid such an ambiguity.

Instead, either specify fully qualified names, like `boost::function`, `boost::bind`, or import particular symbols: `using boost::function;`.

Comment: That is exactly the problem! Thanks.